# vector as a Data Member in C++

Tags: c++, vector

In C++, how do I include a 101 elements vector as a data member in my class? I'm doing the following, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
private:
    std::vector< bool > integers( 101 );
```

I already included the vector header. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `std::array<bool, 101>` or you can have a `std::vector<bool>` and initialize the vector in the constructor of the class: `Class::Class() : integers(101) {}`

Comment: Thank you very much! Is array the same as vector?

Comment: @FernandoKarpinski: No. `array` has a fixed size, with the size specified as part of the type; `vector` grows as needed, and optionally takes a starting size in its constructor.

Comment: Since you wanted it to be statically sized, I assumed you didn't want methods like `push_back` and the like, so `array` should satisfy you.

Comment: A subtle difference with the fixed-size array option: the array contents would be stored in memory contiguously with the rest of MyClass. Using a vector stores the contents separately on the heap. Depending on the usage patterns, this may help or hurt cache performance.

Comment: Another subtle difference -- a `vector` is efficiently swappable and movable-from, whereas an `array` is not. So as a consequence, if you use a `vector` then your class can be efficiently swappable and movable-from. If you don't need that then this difference doesn't matter to you.

Comment: Oh, and another difference is that `std::vector<bool>` is special (and not entirely in a good way). It uses less storage than a `std::array<bool>` of the same size. You might be better off with a `bitset` rather than an `array`, but it really depends how you use it -- `bitset` doesn't have iterators, for example.

Answer (score 12):

```
class myClass {
    std::vector<bool> integers;
public:
    myClass()
        : integers(101)
    {}
};
```

I also like the `std::array` idea. If you really don't need this container to change it's size at run-time, I will suggest going with the the fixed size array option

Comment: +1 for concise concrete example of the still common way (C++03 way).

Answer (score 9):

If you know you will only ever need 101 elements, use `std::array`:

```
class A
{
    //...
private:
    std::array<bool, 101> m_data;
};
```

If you might need more and you just want to give it a default size, use an initializer list:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() : m_data(101) {} // uses the size constructor for std::vector<bool>
private:
    std::vector<bool> m_data;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't use the normal construction syntax to construct an object in the class definition. However, you can use uniform initialization syntax:

```
#include <vector>
class C {
    std::vector<bool> integers{ 101 };
};
```

If you need to use C++03, you have to constructor your vector from a member initializer list instead:

```
C::C(): integers(101) { /* ... */ }
```