# How to make a container member of private sub-class?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have written a class like this:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base():con{5} {}
private:
    class subClass {
        subClass(int t):data{t} {}
        int data;
    };
    vector<subClass> con;
};
```

In this class I'd like to have a container member to store its private sub-class because I think `con` has privilege to access and new `subClass`, but as a result compiler told me:

> test.cpp:8:3: error: ‘Base::subClass::subClass(int)’ is private:
>   subClass(int t):data{t} {}
>   test.cpp:5:14: error: within this
>   context   Base():con{5} {}

So my question is why my code doesn't work. Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vector as a Data Member in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849484/vector-as-a-data-member-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that subClass does not provide a public constructor, so provide one

```
class Base {
public:
    Base():con{5} {}
private:
    class subClass {
        int data;
    public:
        subClass(int t):data(t) {}
    };
    vector<subClass> con;
};
```

Comment: Your code is subtly different to the original, you are constructing `Base:con(5)` rather than `Base:con{5}`, which construct vectors with quite different content

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the statement

```
Base():con{5} {}
```

attempts to to initialise the vector `con` with an instance of `subClass` constructed using the value `5`.

However the corresponding constructor

```
subClass(int t):data(t) {}
```

is currently **private**.

Even though `subClass` is a private member of `Base`, the usual visibility rules apply.  `Base` cannot see `subClass::subClass(int)` unless it is public:

```
class subClass {
public:
    subClass(int t): data(t) {}
private:
    int data;
}
```