# c++ - help understanding differences between function and class templates

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, stdvector

I'm trying to implement a C++ program that, given a list of elements, prints out unique elements from the list.

I know C a lot better than C++, but I am starting out on C++ *practically* (coding) only now.

I've only read up on C++ concepts what templates are and I'm comfortable with function templates but I just read up on class templates and I think I'm getting confused as to where to use which one, as applied to the scenario below.

Here's what I've written so far (*note that the function isUnique is supposed to be doing something else but I'm writing just verifiable actions inside it for now):

**cppArrays.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template <class T> class cpparray{
private:
    int size;
    vector<T> elems;
public:
    cpparray(int);
    ~ cpparray();
    int isUnique(T arr);
};


template <class T> cpparray<T>::cpparray(int size)
{
    vector<T> elems(size);
    cout << "Object created with size " << elems.size()<< "\n"<< endl;
}
template <class T> cpparray<T>::~cpparray()
{
    cout << "Object del\n" << endl;
}

template <class T> int cpparray<T>::isUnique(T arr)
{
    return arr.size();
}
```

**cppArrays.cc**

```
#include "cppArrays.h"

int main()
{
    cpparray<int> a(10) ;
    //a.push_back(1);
    //a.push_back(2);
    //cout << a.size() << a.begin() << a.end() << endl;
    int b = isUnique(a);
    return 0;
}
```

**Details**:

[1] I'm trying to use templates, because I want my *vector* to be able to be instantiated with any data type - char/float/int.

[2] I realize that in using a class template, by calling

```
cpparray<int>a(10);
```

I end up declaring an object a of class "cpparray" whose type is Integer. Is this correct?
If yes, then `a.push_back(1)` wouldn't work because it doesn't refer to the member variable but the object itself and hence it's understandable I'll get a compile time error saying **no member named push_back in cpparray**.

But this is making it even more difficult for me to

[1] understand when to use *class* template as opposed to *function* template,

[2] How do I initialize this vector in the template class and work with it, given my objective?

Comment: `push_back` should exist as a member function of `array`. Then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list). `elems` in your constructor is a local instance.

Comment: Precisely. But I'm trying to use the std container vector, but I'm messing up the part where I try to generalize the class array to work with vector of any type of data.

Comment: I would say you're messing up the part that comes before templates in a C++ introductory book in the case of that initialization attempt. And asking *"class template vs function template"* is a bit like *"class vs function"*.

Comment: @Raaj -- Please don't call your home-made class `array`.  There already is a `std::array` class in C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie noted. Will call it something else. Thanks! That wouldn't still help me figure out what I'm doing wrong :/

Comment: @Raaj -- You skipped the important chapter in your C++ book that discusses the "member initialization list" of the constructor.  You failed to use it to initialize the vector member.  All you did in your constructor was create a temporary vector called `elems` -- you didn't change anything to your member variable `elems`.

Comment: @Raaj -- Also, get rid of the `size` member variable.  It is not necessary, as a `vector` knows its own size by calling the `size()` member function.  Carrying around unnecessary size variables only can lead to bugs occurring.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vector as a Data Member in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849484/vector-as-a-data-member-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor should use initialization list to init members,

like this:

```
template <class T> array<T>::array(int sz) :  size(sz), elems(sz)
{
    cout << "Object created with size " << elems.size()<< "\n"<< endl;
}
```

What you did is to declare the vector as local in the constructor, init it to size, and the local vector was destroyed at the end of block.

Answer (score 2):

Use a class template when you need a generic *type* that has compile-time variable properties. Template parameters can be types *and* constants, e.g.

```
template<typename T, size_t Size>
class MyArray {
    T elements_[Size];
public:
    MyArray() {}
    // ...
};
```

Use a function template when wish to write a generic function that can be applied to various types/parameters:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

template<size_t BufSize, typename... Args>
int strprintf(char(&buf)[BufSize], const char* fmt, Args&&... args)
{
    static_assert(BufSize > 0, "Buffer too small");
    static_assert(BufSize < (1 << 31), "Buffer too large");
    return snprintf(buf, BufSize, fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
    char buf[16];
    int printed = strprintf(buf, "hello world %s so long", "oversized load");
    std::cout << buf << "\n";
}
```

http://ideone.com/SLUQX3

The above is an example of how you can replace one of those old vsnprintf forwarding printf-type functions; doing all the legwork at compile time makes it drastically more efficient.

`BufSize` can be deduced by the compiler because the type of `buf` is `char[16]`; it can capture the source by reference, the type is char and the array size - the template variable - is 16.

It's also possible to have a templated member function of a templated class:

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
    T t_;
public:
    Foo() : t_() {}
    Foo(const T& t) : t_(t) {}

    template<typename RhsT>
    bool is_same_size(const RhsT& rhs) {
        return t_.size() == rhs.size();
    }
};
```

This example will only work for instances when both T and RhsT have a size() member function, leading to the following:

```
Foo<vector<int>> fvi;
Foo<list<double>> fld;
fvi.is_same_size(fld);  // fine
Foo<int> fi;
fvi.is_same_size(fi);  // compiler error
```